# How to use tagged prompts with call/cc in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations

Why this code

```lisp
(let ([cc #f]
      [pr (make-continuation-prompt-tag 'pr)])
  (call-with-continuation-prompt
   (λ () (displayln
          (+ 2 (call-with-current-continuation
                (λ (k) (set! cc k) 1)
                pr))))
   pr)
  (cc 4))
```

(on Racket v7.5) raise exception?:

```lisp
3
; continuation application: no corresponding prompt in the current continuation
; Context:
;  /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/repl.rkt:11:26
```

---

While same code with default tag works as expected:

```lisp
(let ([cc #f])
  (call-with-continuation-prompt
   (λ ()
     (displayln (+ 2 (call-with-current-continuation
                      (λ (k) (set! cc k) 1))))))
  (cc 4))
```

```
3
6
```

---

And same (as the first snippet) code with composable continuation

```lisp
(let ([cc #f]
      [pr (make-continuation-prompt-tag 'pr)])
  (call-with-continuation-prompt
   (λ () (displayln
          (+ 2 (call-with-composable-continuation
                (λ (k) (set! cc k) 1)
                pr))))
   pr)
  (cc 4))
```

works as expected too:

```lisp
3
6
```

---

What is wrong with the first snippet? Or what is wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs for call-with-current-continuation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-current-continuation%29%29):

> If the continuation argument to proc is ever applied, then it removes the portion of the current continuation up to the nearest prompt tagged by prompt-tag (not including the prompt; if no such prompt exists, the exn:fail:contract:continuation exception is raised), ....

In your first example, when you apply `cc`, there is no prompt for `pr` in the context ("on the stack") *when the application occurs*, so it raises an exception.

The second example works because there is always a prompt for the default tag.

The third example works because `call-with-composable-continuation` creates a continuation procedure that does not abort the current continuation, so there is no precondition for its application. (That's part of why it's considered a "composable" continuation.)

---

If it helps, here is *approximately* how `call/cc` can be defined in terms of the `abort-current-continuation` and `call-with-compposable-continuation`. (Warning: I haven't tested this, so there may be bugs.) In the type annotations below, I use the following conventions: `P` is the result type associated with a prompt tag and `A` is the result type of a `call/cc` or `call/comp` call, which is also the type of the continuation's argument. `⊥` is the empty type; it effectively means "doesn't return".

```
;; call-with-continuation-prompt : (-> P) PromptTag[P] -> P
;; Only allows default abort handler!

;; abort-current-continuation : PromptTag[P] (-> P) -> ⊥
;; Assumes the default abort handler!

;; call-with-composable-continuation : ((A -> P) -> A) PromptTag[P] -> A

;; call/cc : ((A -> ⊥) -> A) PromptTag[P] -> A
(define (call/cc proc tag)
  (call-with-composable-continuation
   (lambda (ck) ;; ck : A -> P
     ;; k : A -> ⊥
     (define (k v)
       (abort-current-continuation tag
         (lambda () (ck v))))
     (proc k))
   tag))
```

This definition doesn't account for how `call/cc` actually interacts with `dynamic-wind`, it doesn't work with custom prompt handlers, and it doesn't account for multiple return values (which correspond to multiple continuation arguments), but it should give you a rough idea of what `call/cc` is doing. In particular, the call to `abort-current-continuation` requires that the current continuation has a prompt tagged with `tag`.

Comment: Thanks! I understood what my mistake was: I thought that the highlighted paragraph from the documentation applies only when calling from `proc` passed to `call/cc`, but not to call of saved continuation.